# What method is needed to have the "-" ( subtract ) method working with Ruby arrays?

Tags: ruby, arrays, subtraction

If I have two arrays `a` and `b`, what method should the object contained have to override so the subtract method `-` works properly?

Is it enough with `eql?`

**EDIT**

I'm adding more detail to my question.

I have this class defined:

```
class Instance
    attr_reader :id, :desc 
    def initialize( id ,  desc  )
        @id = id.strip
        @desc = desc.strip
    end

    def sameId?( other )
        @id == other.id
    end

    def eql?( other )
        sameId?( other ) and @desc == other.desc
    end

    def to_s()
        "#{id}:#{desc}"
    end
end
```

Ok?

Then I have filled my two arrays from different parts and I want to get the difference.

```
a = Instance.new("1","asdasdad")
b = Instance.new("1","a")
c = Instance.new("1","a")

p a.eql?(b) #false
p b.eql?(c) #true 

x = [a,b]
y = [c]

z = x - y # should leave a because b and c "represent" the same object
```

But this is not working, because `a` and `b` are being kept in the array. I'm wondering what method to I need to override in my class for this to work properly.

Comment: Can you define "works properly" ? Right now, subtracting array2 from array1 one removes any item in array1 that exists in array2. I guess it seems like that is the desired effect.

Comment: @dcneiner: For every object? ... I'm defining... let me put that on the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to redefine `#eql?` and the [hash](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Object.html#M000337) method.

You may define it as:

```
def hash
    id.hash + 32 * desc.hash
end
```

Details:

To see what's being called in Ruby 1.9:

```
    % irb
    >> class Logger < BasicObject
    >>   def initialize(delegate)
    >>     @delegate = delegate
    >>   end
    >>   def method_missing(m,*args,&blk)
    >>     ::STDOUT.puts [m,args,blk].inspect
    >>     @delegate.send(m,*args,&blk)
    >>   end
    >> end
    => nil
    >> object = Logger.new(Object.new)
    [:inspect, [], nil]
    => #<Object:0x000001009a02f0>
    >> [object] - [0]
    [:hash, [], nil]
    [:inspect, [], nil]
    => [#<Object:0x000001009a02f0>]
    >> zero = Logger.new(0)
    [:inspect, [], nil]
    => 0
    >> [zero] - [0]
    [:hash, [], nil]
    [:eql?, [0], nil]
    => []
```

The same is true in ruby 1.8.7

```
    % irb18
    >> class Logger < Object
    >>   instance_methods.each { |m| undef_method m }
    >>   def initialize(delegate)
    >>     @delegate = delegate
    >>   end
    >>   def method_missing(m,*args,&blk)
    >>     ::STDOUT.puts [m,args,blk].inspect
    >>     @delegate.send(m,*args,&blk)
    >>   end
    >> end
    (irb):2: warning: undefining `__send__' may cause serious problem
    (irb):2: warning: undefining `__id__' may cause serious problem
    => nil
    >> object = Logger.new(Object.new)
    [:inspect, [], nil]
    => #<Object:0x100329690>
    >> [object] - [0]
    [:hash, [], nil]
    [:inspect, [], nil]
    => [#<Object:0x100329690>]
    >> zero = Logger.new(0)
    [:inspect, [], nil]
    => 0
    >> [zero] - [0]
    [:hash, [], nil]
    [:eql?, [0], nil]
    => []
```

Comment: mmhh let's see... ruby -version : I have 1.8.7 :(

Comment: uhh... :)  I think that's a bit too advanced for me just yet..... let me chew it for a while ;)

Comment: Ok, I did `def hash` and include this: `id.has + 32 * desc.hash` and still it is not working. What am I missing?

Comment: Well at least I can see it is being called. Am I to override eql? also?

Comment: Nice one! So actually you should define a good hash-function for objects, and then the eql? function is indeed straightforward (comparing the hashes).

Comment: @nathanvda: No. Hashes are finite, the number of possible objects is infinite, therefore the pigeonhole principle applies: there will be at least two objects which are not `eql?` but have the same `hash`.